# error whie running the app in my android device

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, device, android-spinner

"Hi,

I made a small app and i tried running it in AVD and it was successfully running without any problem.
Now when i exported that .apk file to my android device and tried running it, it works properly at the beginning stage but when i navigate to the last activity of the app,the data is not loading in the spinner. The data are parsed from the JSON in background and is added to the spinner via adapter.

I want possible answers why this is happening.

Thanks in advance."

Comment: were you loading data from a remote server when your app was running in avd or localhost ?

Comment: post your code for better help.

Comment: post logcat from phone.. seems Network problem should have occurred.. check that

Comment: After doing a lot of stuffs, I finally figured it out and got the answer yesterday..... Now its working absolutely fine in mobile also. Anyways thanks for your kind suggestions everyone.